# RapidMiner converting dates to missing values upon CSV import

Tags: date, csv, import, rapidminer

I'm using the option "import CSV file" into a local repository.  The file has a .csv extension.  The date is in the format 10/12/2014.
An example row: 321,10/12/2014,0.032839,...
What's imported: 321,?,0.032839,...
During import, after changing from the default delimiter ";" to "," the attributes are separated correctly, and on the next screen I select "date" as the data type for that attribute.

RapidMiner 5.3.013.  Windows 8.0.

Comment: Are you sure the date format isn't `12/10/2014`? And how would you distinguish them? P.S. You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: ?? If either 12/10/2014 or 10/12/2014 is a valid date, then the other one is also valid (but one of them is wrong - but that's not the issue here).  The question is how do you import dates, and another person here has provided an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the format of the date to be "dd/MM/yyyy" (case is important). The parameter is `date_format` within the `Read CSV` operator.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into how to do that.  I have upgraded to 6.5. Since you know RapidMiner, can you answer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537686/rapidminer-hangs-on-basic-task-fresh-install  ? --  It's been a week and I have not been approved for the apps forum, and I'm about to uninstall it.