# RapidMiner Hangs on Basic Task (Fresh Install)

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, data-analysis, rapidminer

I selected the first 50,000 rows of the Homesite dataset - a current Kaggle competition.  (30MB out of the full 200MB in the dataset.)  I imported the .csv file and connected it to a Random Forest model. I changed one default - the RF will build 50 trees rather than 10.

If I click on any other task icon after I start the process the laptop hangs, requiring a power down - which I've never had to do before.  If I don't select any other icon and just stay in RapidMiner, it hangs at 1:15 (the displayed timer).

This was my very first attempt at using RapidMiner Studio 6.5.  I have the much older RapidMiner 5, which doesn't hang, but it is painfully slow as compared to r, and it doesn't even have Random Forests or many other models found in 6.5.  6.5 is also supposed to be much faster, and it is supposed to be able to use r scripts.

I performed a complete checkup on my Dell laptop.  Everything passes.
I ran a complete scan with MalwareBytes.
I don't have any issues with any other software.
R builds neural networks (etc) at the expected speeds without any problems.

RapidMiner Studio 6.5 (64 Bit; Basic Edition)
Windows 8.0 (64 Bit); Intel Core I3 @2 Ghz; 6 GB Ram.

Comment: What's your memory usage like when this is happening? Random forests can be a memory hungry algorithm and if it chews through all the available memory and starts on the swap space it could quickly slow everything to a crawl.

Comment: The last time I tried it I had no other apps running, not even the firewall and anti-virus.  It hung just the same.

Comment: What about if you try with another set of data, such as the Kaggle Titanic data?

Comment: I imagine there is some small dataset that wouldn't be a problem.  I need it to run on the Homesite dataset, the whole 200MB, not just the 20MB it's crashing on.

Comment: You can see the memory usage by enabling the appropriate view from the RapidMiner GUI. I suggest trying a really tiny dataset to see what the memory usage is and then increase it to see what happens.

Comment: I enabled the system monitor, which is the only thing I see. It says "3.4 GB used. Will use up to 5.2 GB." I set the RF to generate 5 trees, then 10, then 15. 15 was fine, and it generated them in a few seconds. When set to 20 tree, the monitor showed it was using half the resouces, and then it seemed to hang at 22 seconds. I waited a few minutes and I was able to view the 20 trees, although the laptop was extremely non-responsive, and there was a several second pause after every click. ...

Comment: ... After a couple minutes it seemed responsive again, until I selected a different app (Firefox), which would not respond. Rapidminer was then non-responsive. I finally managed to close rapidminer, and that restarted Explorer, which reloaded all my icons again, and the system is now okay. This is not workable, as it is right now.